# sudo apt-get install python-wheel on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, python-wheel

I'm trying to install `python-wheel` on Ubuntu 12.04, but get an error:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wheel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-wheel
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Add this unofficial PPA :

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/python-wheel

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-wheel

Reference link : https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/python-wheel

**Ubuntu version :**

*Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise*